# Why does it throws an error while putting functions into header in VSCode but not GCC?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linker-errors, header-files, undefined-reference

I'm programming a game in C using VS Code as my IDE and wanted to put my functions into a header file. So now I have `ship-cap-crew.c`, `gamefunct.c` and `gamefunct.h`. When I try to use `#include "gamefunct.h"`, I get an error: `(.text+0xac): undefined reference to 'playercount'`, and the same from all of the other functions called from main.

This goes away when I use `#include "gamefunct.c"` or if I use GCC to run the code rather than from VS Code. I just want to be able to run the code straight from Visual Studio.

Comment: you need to compile both and link together ship-cap-crew.c gamefunct.c . At the moment you do not link it

Comment: VS Code is not compiling the code, but GCC does, even if you initiate the compilation from VS Code. VS Code is not running the code, but your operating system is running the compiled and linked executable program directly.

Comment: Your question mentions both *VS Code* and *Visual Studio*, which are two different IDEs by Microsoft. Which one are you actually using? Please remove references to the other one from your question.

Comment: Most likely the solution to your problem is defining a project in VS Code and mentioning both ship-cap-crew.c and gamefunct.c in the project definition. (I don't know in detail how to do that in VS Code.)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "use gcc to run the code"? show the exact commands you use to compile and link.